# How do you combine KNN and Adaboost with SKlearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

is it possible to do adaboost classifier with `estimator = KNeighborsClassifier` ?

If not, how else can I apply boosting to KNN ?

Comment: You should probably explain a bit more what you are willing to do, and, what you mean by applying boosting (adaboost?) to KNN

Comment: Why do you want to apply boosting to KNN? Is it something like ball-tree or kd-tree algorithm to help KNN?

Comment: Compared to [DecisionTreeClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html), [KNeighborsClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier) does not have the attributes ```classes_/n_classes_```, which is requirement as stated in [AdaBoostClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) docs: ```Support for sample weighting is required, as well as proper classes_ and n_classes_ attributes.```.